# Laravel 5 - can't override the connection in Eloquent Model

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, eloquent

My basic task is to use the `wp_users` table from WordPress for user authentication. The WordPress installation has a different database, connection to which I've created and named `wordpress`.

I've found a pretty amazing package `jgrossi/corcel`, which basically does everything I need! It comes with `Corcel\User`, which I am extending with my `App\User` Eloquent model, because I need it to use the `wordpress` database connection. Here's what it looks like:

```
<?php

namespace App;

class User extends \Corcel\User
{
    protected $connection   = "wordpress";
}
```

The problem with that is, it defaults back to the default connection. If I change the member variable `$connection` in the `Corcel\User` Eloquent model, it just works!

How do I change the connection in the `App\User` without changing the code in the `jgrossi/corcel` package?

Comment: Just to make sure: do you have your extended User class set as user model in `config/auth.php`? Under providers -> users -> model.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! Yes, I do. Just like that: 
`'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'corcel',
            'model'  => App\User::class,
        ],
    ],`